# Search nested array of objects and return whole path of all matching items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion, data-structures, nested

I would like to search a deeply nested array of objects and return the path of all matched objects. I have partial solution of the problem but the code returns path of only first matched object. Please have a look at the input, expected output and the code itself. I have commented the desired logic in the expected output section.

Thanks in advance. Please help me out.

**The Input Data**

```
   [
   {
      "label":"Home",
      "key":"home",
      "level":1,
      "children":[
         {
            "label":"Indoor Furniture",
            "key":"furniture",
            "level":2,
            "children":[
               {
                  "label":"Chair",
                  "key":"chair",
                  "level":3
               },
               {
                  "label":"Table",
                  "key":"table",
                  "level":3
               },
               {
                  "label":"Lamp",
                  "key":"lamp",
                  "level":3
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "label":"Outdoor",
      "key":"outdoor",
      "level":1,
      "children":[
         {
            "label":"Outdoor Furniture",
            "key":"furniture",
            "level":2,
            "children":[
               {
                  "label":"Trampoline",
                  "key":"trampoline",
                  "level":3
               },
               {
                  "label":"Swing",
                  "key":"swing",
                  "level":3
               },
               {
                  "label":"Large sofa",
                  "key":"large sofa",
                  "level":3
               },
               {
                  "label":"Medium Sofa",
                  "key":"mediumSofa",
                  "level":3
               },
               {
                  "label":"Small Sofa Wooden",
                  "key":"smallSofaWooden",
                  "level":3
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "label":"Games",
            "key":"games",
            "level":2,
            "children":[
               
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "label":"Refurbrished Items",
      "key":"refurbrished items",
      "level":1,
      "children":[
         
      ]
   },
   {
      "label":"Indoor",
      "key":"indoor",
      "level":1,
      "children":[
         {
            "label":"Electicity",
            "key":"electicity",
            "level":2,
            "children":[
               
            ]
         },
         {
            "label":"Living Room Sofa",
            "key":"livingRoomSofa",
            "level":2,
            "children":[
               
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

**Expected Output - if sofa is searched**

```
[
// Remove the entire object if label of the object itself or any of its children doesn't include sofa
      {
         "label":"Outdoor",
         "key":"outdoor",
         "level":1,
         "children":[
            {
               "label":"Indoor Furniture",
               "key":"indoorFurniture",
               "level":2,
               "children":[
// Remove unmatched siblings
                  { `// Child node matched, hence return its path from root (Outdoor -> Indoor Furniture)`  
                     "label":"Large sofa",
                     "key":"large sofa",
                     "level":3
                  },
                  { // Child node matched, hence return its path from root (Outdoor -> Indoor Furniture) and all its children if any
                     "label":"Medium Sofa",
                     "key":"mediumSofa",
                     "level":3
                  },
                  { // Child node matched, hence return its path from root (Outdoor -> Indoor Furniture) and all its children if any
                     "label":"Small Sofa Wooden",
                     "key":"smallSofaWooden",
                     "level":3
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "label":"Indoor",
         "key":"indoor",
         "level":1,
         "children":[
            { // Child node matched, hence return its path from root (Indoor) and all its children if any
               "label":"Living Room Sofa",
               "key":"livingRoomSofa",
               "level":2,
               "children":[
                  
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
```

**Expected Output - if furniture is searched**

```
[ // Remove the entire object if label of the object itself or any of its children doesn't include furniture
          {
             "label":"Home",
             "key":"home",
             "level":1,
             "children":[
                { // Child node matched, hence return its path from root (Home) and all its children if any
                   "label":"Indoor Furniture",
                   "key":"indoorFurniture",
                   "level":2,
                   "children":[
                      {
                         "label":"Chair",
                         "key":"chair",
                         "level":3
                      },
                      {
                         "label":"Table",
                         "key":"table",
                         "level":3
                      },
                      {
                         "label":"Lamp",
                         "key":"lamp",
                         "level":3
                      }
                   ]
                }
             ]
          },
          {
             "label":"Outdoor",
             "key":"outdoor",
             "level":1,
             "children":[
                { // Child node matched, hence return its path from root (Outdoor) and all its children if any
                   "label":"Outdoor Furniture",
                   "key":"outdoorFurniture",
                   "level":2,
                   "children":[
                      {
                         "label":"Trampoline",
                         "key":"trampoline",
                         "level":3
                      },
                      {
                         "label":"Swing",
                         "key":"swing",
                         "level":3
                      },
                      {
                         "label":"Large sofa",
                         "key":"large sofa",
                         "level":3
                      },
                      {
                         "label":"Medium Sofa",
                         "key":"mediumSofa",
                         "level":3
                      },
                      {
                         "label":"Small Sofa Wooden",
                         "key":"smallSofaWooden",
                         "level":3
                      }
                   ]
                }
             ]
          }
       ]
```

**The code**

```
function findChild(obj, condition) {
if (Object.entries(condition).every( ([k,v]) => (obj[k].toLowerCase()).includes(v.toLowerCase()))) {
    return obj;
}
for (const child of obj.children || []) {
    const found = findChild(child, condition);
    // If found, then add this node to the ancestors of the result
    if (found) return Object.assign({}, obj, { children: [found] });
 }
}
var search = { label: 'sofa' };
console.log(findChild(input, search)); // It returns only the first matched item path, i would like to get all matched items path
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like it will do it:

```js
const filterDeep = (pred) => (xs, kids) =>
  xs .flatMap (
    x => 
      pred (x)
        ? [x]
      : (kids = filterDeep (pred) (x .children || [])) && kids.length
        ? [{... x, children: kids}] 
      : []
    
  )

const testIncludes = (condition) => (obj) =>
  Object .entries (condition) .every (
    ([k, v]) => (obj [k] || '') .toLowerCase () .includes (v .toLowerCase ())
  )

const filterMatches = (obj, conditions) =>
  filterDeep (testIncludes (conditions)) (obj)


const input = [{label: "Home", key: "home", level: 1, children: [{label: "Indoor Furniture", key: "furniture", level: 2, children: [{label: "Chair", key: "chair", level: 3}, {label: "Table", key: "table", level: 3}, {label: "Lamp", key: "lamp", level: 3}]}]}, {label: "Outdoor", key: "outdoor", level: 1, children: [{label: "Outdoor Furniture", key: "furniture", level: 2, children: [{label: "Trampoline", key: "trampoline", level: 3}, {label: "Swing", key: "swing", level: 3}, {label: "Large sofa", key: "large sofa", level: 3}, {label: "Medium Sofa", key: "mediumSofa", level: 3}, {label: "Small Sofa Wooden", key: "smallSofaWooden", level: 3}]}, {label: "Games", key: "games", level: 2, children: []}]}, {label: "Refurbrished Items", key: "refurbrished items", level: 1, children: []}, {label: "Indoor", key: "indoor", level: 1, children: [{label: "Electicity", key: "electicity", level: 2, children: []}, {label: "Living Room Sofa", key: "livingRoomSofa", level: 2, children: []}]}]


console .log ('sofa:', filterMatches (input, {label: 'sofa'}))
console .log ('furniture:', filterMatches (input, {label: 'furniture'}))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We separate out the recursive filtering mechanism, and also the object-matching part, putting them back together in `filterMatches`.  The idea is that we might want to filter by many means, so the function takes an arbitrary predicate function that can test the current node. `testIncludes` takes an object of key-value pairs and returns a function which takes an object and reports whether the object' corresponding keys each includes the relevant value.  (I added case-insensitive checking here based on your input / requested output combination.)

Note that I named the central function with the word `filter` rather than `find`, as `find` generally implies returning the first match, whereas `filter` is supposed to return *all* matches.

---

For my own use, I would structure the main function slightly differently:

```js
const filterMatches = (conditions) => (obj) =>
  filterDeep (testIncludes (conditions)) (obj)

console .log ('sofa:', filterMatches ({label: 'sofa'}) (input))
```

I like these curried functions a great deal, and with the parameters in that order I feel they are most useful.  But YMMV.

## Update

A comment noted a lint failure for the main function.  It's an understandable one, as this did something tricky in using an assignment inside a conditional expression.  So here are some working variants:

- **Moving the assignment to a default parameter:**

  ```js
  const filterDeep = (pred) => (xs, kids) =>
    xs .flatMap (
      (x, _, __, kids = filterDeep (pred) (x .children || [])) => 
        pred (x)
          ? [x]
        : kids.length
          ? [{... x, children: kids}] 
        : [] 
    )
  ```

  **Pros:**

  - This keeps our expression-only style alive, and avoids the trickiness above.
  - It's fairly easy to read

  **Cons:**

  - It uses default parameters, which have their problems.
  - It requires naming two unused parameters from `flatMat` (Here `_` and `__`.)
- **Using statement style:**

  ```js
  const filterDeep = (pred) => (xs, kids) =>
    xs .flatMap ((x) => {
      if (pred (x)) {
        return [x]
      }
      const kids = filterDeep (pred) (x .children || [])
      if (kids.length > 0) {
        return [{... x, children: kids}] 
      }
      return []
    })
  ```

  **Pros:**

  - No more trickiness of any sort
  - More accessible for beginners

  **Cons:**

  - `if` and `return` are *statements* and statements lead to less modular code than working with pure *expressions*.
- **Using a `call` helper function:**

  ```
  const call = (fn, ...args) => fn (...args)

  const filterDeep = (pred) => (xs, kids) =>
    xs .flatMap (
      (x) => 
        pred (x)
          ? [x]
        : call (
          (kids) => kids.length ? [{... x, children: kids}] : [], 
          filterDeep (pred) (x .children || [])
        )
    )
  ```

  **Pros:**

  - A `call` helper function is all-around useful and can be reused in many places.
  - It avoids any fiddling with parameters

  **Cons:**

  - This combines the last two clauses of what is really a three-part test (returning `[x]`, returning `[{... x, children: kids}]`, and returning `[]`) into a single function

I have a slight preference for that last version.  But any of them would do.

Comment: What a master piece! Thank you so much. Exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: ESLinter doesn't like this line (kids = filterDeep (pred) (x .children || [])) && kids.length it throws an error assignment operators in conditional statements (no-cond-assign)

Comment: It *is* overly tricky. There's probably a good reason for that linter rule.  We can put that assignment as a default value in the parameters:  `const filterDeep = (pred) => (xs, kids = filterDeep (pred) (x .children || [])) => ...` and then just use `kids.length` (or better `kids.length > 0`) in the condition.  This has a slight inefficiency, which doesn't worry me much.  Or you could rewrite with some `if` statements and only declare and calculate `kids` if you've already moved beyond the first test.

Comment: Thanks! const filterDeep = (pred) => (xs, kids = filterDeep (pred) (x .children || [])) => ... here x would be undefined i belive. isn't it?

Comment: Yes, sorry.  That's what I get for coding without testing!  I'll see if I can find something better that's clean.

Comment: hahah. BDW i tried throwing in some if else to make it clean. Now Linter is happy but filter functionality is gone.  `code` filterMarchedItems = pred => (cats, childCats) =>
    cats.flatMap(cat => {
      if (pred(cat)) {
        return [cat];
      } else {
        const kids = this.filterMarchedItems(pred)(cat.children || []);
        if (kids.length > 0) {
          return [
            {
              ...cat,
              children: childCats,
            },
          ];
        } else {
          return [];
        }
      } `code`

Comment: Added alternative versions of that main function.

Comment: Thanks for the huge efforts. With the updated version linter is happy and functionality remains intact!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will suffice:

```
const findTerm = (arr, term) => arr.filter(e => JSON.stringify(e).indexOf(term) >= 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it returns the entire matched object, but the requirement is to remove the  unmatched children